# Calculating time in seconds using bash

Tags: bash, datetime

I have cron job which processes data every 15 minutes(12:00, 12:15, etc...)  I need a bash function/script which determines how many seconds until the next processing cycle relative to the current time.  If current time = "15:09:00 2016"
the next processing cycle would be 360 sec.  Any ideas?  thanks.

Comment: How about `date -d "+ 6 min"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the current time in seconds since the UNIX epoch

```
$ now=$(date +%s)
```

then compute that value mod 900 (900 seconds is 15 minutes) and subtract that from 900.

```
$ echo $((900 - now % 900))
```

Comment: I was going to post something similar, but got caught up in timezones -- be aware that epoch is UTC and if you're in some odd timezone, and using something like 3600 secs instead, you could be off.  But for most cases, this is good enough.

Comment: Nice. To find the *next* 15-minute time: `date -d "@$(( now=$(date +%s), now + (900-now%900) ))" +%H:%M`

Answer (score 1):

The `date` command allows a date to be provided following the `-d --date` option. `date` also understands relative dates (e.g. `+ 6 min`, `+3 days`, etc..). So if you need to know what `6` minutes in the future is you can simply use `date -d "+ 6 min"` to find the exact time that will be. e.g.

```
$ date
Fri Jun 10 15:22:45 CDT 2016

$ date -d "+ 6 min"
Fri Jun 10 15:28:47 CDT 2016
```

Comment: I think this is only supported by GNU date